# Liquid control flow tags {% for %} and {% else %}

Tags: shopify, liquid, control-flow

Still new to using liquid in Shopify themes, and documentation is lacking in a few areas, so I'm in "learn as you go" mode, and I'm rebuilding Shopify's Simple theme from scratch as a learning tool. I cam across this bit of code in collection-template.liquid:

```
1   {% for product in collection.products %}
2       {% if collection.products.size == 1 %}
3           <!-- Template Logic -->
4       {% else %}
5           <!-- Template Logic -->
6       {% endif %}
7           
8       {% include 'product-grid-item' %}
9
10  {% else %} <!-- HANGING ELSE STATEMENT? -->
11
12      <!-- Template Logic -->
13
14      {% if shop.products_count == 0 and collection.handle == 'all' %}
15          <!-- Template Logic -->
16      {% else %}
17          <!-- Template Logic -->
18      {% endif %}
19  {% endfor %}
```

Coming from a Java background, line 10 looks like a compile error. It's an `else` statement with no opening `if`.

But, based on context clues, I'm wondering if that `{% else %}` is like an `if (empty)`, which would mean the above snippet would be functionally equivalent to:

```
{% if collection.products.size == 0 %}
    <!-- Line 11-18 from above snippet -->
{% else %}
    {% for product in collection.products %}
        <!-- Line 2-9 from above snippet -->
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a fallback for the case where the collection used by the for loop has zero length. See https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/iteration-tags#else

Comment: Perfect, thanks. That's what I thought. I must have missed that when I was scanning the documentation.